# calling form submit by choosing an element from select

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make form to be submitted when user selects an element from select dropdown list; below is the code i wrote, but its not working. I added console statements to see code gets executed as per my understanding. Can anyone please help in making this code work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <form id="form">
    <select name='toggle' id='toggle' onchange="this.form.submit()">
                              <option value="default">Default</option>
                              <option value="details">Details</option>
                            </select>
  </form>

  <!--Javascript-->
  <script>
    var form = document.getElementById('form')

    form.addEventListener('submit',function(event){
      console.log("in submit");
      var username = document.getElementById("username").value
      console.log(username)

    })

    
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Remove the onChnage attribute and try.

Comment: you better wrap your script in a function and call it onchange.

Comment: Its not working yet, i tried above suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to programmatically submit the form and then handling the event like you try to do now.

See the [SumbitEvent MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event) for more information.

> The event is not sent to the form when calling the form.submit() method directly.

Instead what you can do is add a `change` event listener on your `select` element and listen for any change there. This way you can still do "stuff" with your selected option. `form.submit()` will submit the form but just not send an event.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <form id="form">
      <select name="toggle" id="toggle">
        <option value="default">Default</option>
        <option value="details">Details</option>
      </select>
    </form>

    <!--Javascript-->
    <script>
      var form = document.getElementById("form");
      var select = document.getElementById("toggle");

      select.addEventListener("change", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(event.target.value);
        // form.submit();
        // uncommenting this will submit the form
        // but the page will be reloaded so you can't see the console.log
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps you with your project!